# Execute multiple commands with && in systemd service ExecStart on RedHat 7.9

Tags: redhat, systemd

I have this systemd service on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)

```
[Unit]
Description = EUM Server Service
PartOf=eum.service
# Start this unit after the app.service start
After=eum.service
After=eum-db.service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/prod/appdynamics/EUMServer/eum-processor/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 45 && /bin/bash bin/eum.sh start
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash bin/eum.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

that fails because it tries to pick everything after `/usr/bin/sleep` as parameters to that command. I just want to execute the `/usr/bin/sleep 45` and on success execute `bin/eum.sh start`. How can I make it work?

```
● eum-server.service - EUM Server Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/eum-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-07-02 00:00:53 CEST; 9min ago
  Process: 13860 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 45 && /bin/bash bin/eum.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 systemd[1]: Starting EUM Server Service...
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 sleep[13860]: /usr/bin/sleep: invalid time interval ‘&&’
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 sleep[13860]: /usr/bin/sleep: invalid time interval ‘/bin/bash’
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 sleep[13860]: /usr/bin/sleep: invalid time interval ‘bin/eum.sh’
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 sleep[13860]: /usr/bin/sleep: invalid time interval ‘start’
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 sleep[13860]: Try '/usr/bin/sleep --help' for more information.
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 systemd[1]: eum-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 systemd[1]: Failed to start EUM Server Service.
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 systemd[1]: Unit eum-server.service entered failed state.
Jul 02 00:00:53 lmlift06mnp001 systemd[1]: eum-server.service failed.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The command line is not given to a shell, so `&&` is not valid. You would need, for example,

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'sleep 45 && /bin/bash bin/eum.sh start'
```

or you could separate the commands into

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 45
ExecStart=/bin/bash bin/eum.sh start
```

Comment: A better way to do running multiple command would be to create a `Type=oneshot` service and use more `ExecStart`s.

Comment: I'll go with the ExecStartPre. Thanks