# Why is setting 'echo V > /dev/watchdog1' not working when inside a 'systemd' service?

Tags: linux, systemd, watchdog

If I manually stop my service and then execute `echo V > /dev/watchdog1`, the watchdog stops properly.

If I do the same `echo` command in my [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) service, I get:

> watchdog did not stop!

```
ExecStopPost=echo V > /dev/watchdog1
```

Why is the behavior not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work for the same reason mentioned in this post: [Execute multiple commands with && in systemd service ExecStart on RedHat 7.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223306/execute-multiple-commands-with-in-systemd-service-execstart-on-redhat-7-9)

The commands from inside a systemd service are not executed in a proper shell environment. Even so, I do not have some kind of source that explicitly states this. From experience, the capabilities of a single systemd exec are the following: Run one command with parameters (not multiple commands, no output redirection, etc.).

Just like in the referenced post, the solution could be writing it as follows:

```
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c 'echo V > /dev/watchdog1'
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but got on the serial port "watchdog: watchdog1: watchdoge did not stop!". After the delay I configured in my app, the OS reboot.

Comment: Just wanted to add that don't forget the watchdog has been started from code that was under ExecStart. I think that code has exclusive access to the watchdog1 file and can't do anything until the process is really "killed" because the same "echo" command works after returning from a systemctl stop myservice

Comment: my bad... it is working. It looks like because I was pushing the result and the errors to a file, it did not work (echo V > /dev/watchdog1 >> myfile 2>> myfile

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with your watchdog through echoes, but I would strongly advise you against it.

An echo opens/closes your watchdog on every run, needing to configure it as a non-stoppable watchdog. Also, for each open/close, you are getting a warning in the [kmsg log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235333/what-is-the-difference-between-proc-kmsg-and-dmsg/28247699#28247699), receiving an unnecessary amount of insane spam.

Do it right; do it by writing your own application and handling its file descriptor. Do not use echoes anymore! See the below example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Read more:
// https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt
#include <linux/watchdog.h>

#define WATCHDOG_DEV "/dev/watchdog"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  /* Open your watchdog */
  int fd = open(WATCHDOG_DEV, O_RDWR);
  if (fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Query timeout */
  int timeout = 0;
  if (ioctl(fd, WDIOC_GETTIMEOUT, &timeout) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot read watchdog timeout: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "The timeout is %d seconds\n", timeout);

  /* Query timeleft */
  int timeleft = 0;
  if (ioctl(fd, WDIOC_GETTIMELEFT, &timeleft) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot read watchdog timeleft: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "The timeleft is %d seconds\n", timeleft);

  /* Touch your watchdog */
  if (ioctl(fd, WDIOC_KEEPALIVE, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot write watchdog keepalive: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "Keepalive written successfully\n");

  /* Stop your watchdog */
  write(fd, "V", 1);

  /* Close your watchdog */
  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

Another (and easier) option could be to setup a ready-made watchdog service. See the [`watchdog`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/watchdog/watchdog.conf.5.en.html) package for Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Looking at your code, I see that you set "V" to /dev/watchdog. In my case, should I change it for /dev/watchdog1 instead or it does not matter?

Comment: @david Change `WATCHDOG_DEV` to your needs, it can be `/dev/watchdog1` too. About writting a `V` character, also known as 'magic close', it allows you to disable your watchdog when `NOWAYOUT=Y` is configured in the watchdog's driver. In other words, if you don't write a magic close and NOWAYOUT=Y, you won't be able to stop the watchdog after closing its file descriptor and your machine will be rebooted. Read more about magic close/nowayout feature in `Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I know this slightly deviates from the OP's question, but you could also delegate watchdog management to systemd, using systemd's socket API instead.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Unit

[Service]
ExecStart=/my/app args
WatchdogSec=30 # 30s, but you can specify whatever you want
# Optional: Restart=on-watchdog # Restart app on watchdog failure
# Optional: WatchdogSignal=SIGABRT # Change signal sent to kill app
#
```

Then, you must periodically reset the watchdog from your app:

```c
sd_notify(0, "WATCHDOG=1");
```

There are also options to ask `systemd` to reboot the machine if a service fails, although I don't remember which one.

If you need more information, you can see a comprehensive guide here: https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/watchdog.html